# Use of unresolved identifier '_ComboItemId'

Tags: ios, swift

Hello friends I am getting a strange error while creating a model class Though i have created the class it shows an error 
any suggestion !!
Thank you

Here is the code

```
import Foundation
class ComboModel {
private var _ComboItemId: String!
private var _ComboMainCategory: String!
private var _ComboCategoryId: String!
}

var ComboItemId : String {
return _ComboItemId // Error Use of unresolved identifier '_ComboItemId'
}

init(ComboItemId : String) {
 self._ComboItemId = ComboItemId // Error Initializers may only be declared within a type
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple user mistake. You've got a class with **private** variables

```
class ComboModel {
    private var _ComboItemId: String!
    private var _ComboMainCategory: String!
    private var _ComboCategoryId: String!
} // your class ends here!!!
```

Now you're trying to access ComboModel classes private variable _ComboItemId.

```
var ComboItemId : String {
    return _ComboItemId // Error Use of unresolved identifier '_ComboItemId'
}
```

**So, this is probably what you're looking for:**

```
class ComboModel {
    private var _ComboItemId: String!
    private var _ComboMainCategory: String!
    private var _ComboCategoryId: String!

    var ComboItemId : String {
        return _ComboItemId
    }

    init(ComboItemId : String) {
        self._ComboItemId = ComboItemId
    }

}
```